# How to express that X was given every 2 days, and Y every other 2 days?

Tags: phrases

If, for example, X is given coffee on days 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, and so forth, and tea on days 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, and so forth, how can I express this as simple as possible (without mentioning even or uneven days)?

My suggestion is: "X was given coffee every two days and tea every other two days."

Is this correct?

Comment: "X was given tea and coffee on alternate days."

Comment: X is/was given coffee and tea on alternate days.

Comment: *X was given coffee on the first day, tea on the next, coffee again the day after, then tea, and so on, alternating between coffee one day and tea the next*. Now you won't have anyone quibbling that *X was given tea and coffee on alternate days* might mean that *X was given both coffee and tea one day and every other day thereafter*. Sure, my suggestion is a mite wordier.

Comment: "X was given tea **or** coffee on alternate days" avoids the possibility that they were given both one day, nothing the next - I don't think that's a likely interpretation but evidently there's one person who does.

Comment: In ordinary English, there is no short, elegant formulation that will unambiguously convey the precise meaning that you have in mind. If it is really, really important to eliminate any possibility of misunderstanding, you probably have to resort to some elaborate formulation as has been suggested by HighPerformanceMark. The need to say something like this is most likely to arise in medical contexts, so there just might be some technical term for it in medicine; the question thus may be worth re-asking on the Medical Sciences Stack Exchange.

Comment: @StuartF If someone wants to be *that* pedantic about it, your version could be interpreted to mean that every other day X got either tea or coffee, but not both, and nothing on the days in between.

Comment: "*X was given coffee **every other day**, and tea on the days in between*"

Comment: "every other two days" is not an idiomatic phrase in English. Instead there are "every 2 days = every 2nd day = every other day = alternate days). There are all the same generally, which mean that something happens one day and does not happen the next day. As for your question, maybe this might work; "He is offered tea or coffee provided that the drink changes every day.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest construction is:

> X was given tea and coffee on alternate days.

> X was given coffee every other day, and tea on the days in between

But neither of these is without potential ambiguities, for example, neither clearly specifies that coffee was on day one.

In ordinary English, there is no short, elegant formulation that will unambiguously convey the precise meaning that you have in mind. If it is really, really important to eliminate any possibility of misunderstanding, you probably have to resort to some elaborate formulation such as

> X was given coffee on the first day, tea on the next, coffee again the day after, then tea, and so on, alternating between coffee one day and tea the next.

Comment: Comments to CW.